# Has anyone done research on average RPG probabilities?

Tags: dice, statistics, game-design

I've been looking at designing an RPG system lately and I'm currently considering where to set the "difficulty" of a roll at to get some satisfying results.

I'm wondering - has anyone researched some "average" RPG probabilities that "feel good"? My guess would be having something like a 50% success chance as a baseline, then turning it up to something like 75%, 87.5%, etc. as proficiency goes up seems to at least sound good on paper, but it would be nice to have a comparison to some games out there.

I'd be interested to know what kind of probabilities have a good "game feel" - how difficult ought it to be to succeed at a roll of some task you're new at, something you're proficient at, and something you're a master of for example.

I know that in systems like D&D your to-hit bonuses and enemy defences both scale, and many games like PbtAs have a somewhat static difficulty. I'm wondering if there are any design docs for roll probabilities, or does anyone have their design experience to share on such numbers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, research has been done.

A google search (I used "tabletop rpg design good probabilities") provides a plethora of useful articles, many of which are free.

I found [this one](https://medium.com/s/wonky-technical/the-surprisingly-technical-process-of-designing-a-tabletop-game-fee64ba88611) by Asher Stevenson in their Wonky & Technical section of Medium.com to be particularly close to what you seem interested in.

I also thought [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RPGdesign/comments/bk74yt/what_are_fun_odds/) succinctly posits another important fact about die odds... they *should* vary by system and setting.

---

If you're looking for guidance on how to meet probability requirements when you've decided the odds that are right for your design, [there are also articles about that](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/a-compendium-of-ways-to-achieve-different-probability-curves-in-a-tabletop-rpg.594262/).